# Visual Studio error with classes in different folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Morning

I am having issues with having my classes in different folders for the same project.

When I run code analysis on the project I get the error:-

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CA0055  CA0055 : Could not load C:\Users\gkonh\Documents\Visual Studio
> ```
>
> 2015\Projects\MarketAnalyser\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\MarketAnalyser.dll.
>   The following error was encountered while reading module
>   'MarketAnalyser': Could not resolve type reference: [MarketAnalyser,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer.TickData.

Even when I the classes are in the same namespace across the two folders I get the error ?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried referencing the other project? select menuitem project then add reference.

then you see a dropdownlist 1 of these items is solution where you can select the other project.

Comment: Ya i checked that , project b has project a as a reference. Thats why Im not getting whats wrong

Comment: i just noticed this "MarketAnalyser.LogicLayer.TickData". is it possible that the reference is correct but you are using a timer and 1 of the 2 doesn't have the reference to the timer?